# minimize a function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

How can I get the gradients of a function using tf.gradients? the below is working when I use GradientDescentOptimizer.minimize(), tf.gradients seems to be evaluating 1 at the deriv of x^2+2 which is 2x

What am I missing ?

```
x = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=True)
y = x**2 + 2

grad = tf.gradients(y, x)
#grad = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(y)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    grad_value = sess.run(grad)
    print(grad_value)
```

Comment: I get the correct answer (2) using your code. Looks ok to me.

Comment: I'm trying to know how to get the gradients with tf.gradients so for example I can use it to manually descend towards x^2+2 = 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the value of `x` which minimizes `x^2 + 2`.

To do so, you need to repeatedly call `GradientDescentOptimizer` until `x` converges to the value which minimizes the function. This is because gradient descent is an iterative technique.

Also, in tensorflow, the method  `minimize` of `GradientDescentOptimizer` does both computing the gradients and then applying them to the relevant variables (`x` in your case). So the code should look like this (Notice I commented the `grad` variable, which is not required unless you want to look at the gradient values):

```
x = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=True)
y = x**2 + 2

# grad = tf.gradients(y, x)
grad_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(y)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

n_iterations = 10
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(n_iterations):
        _, new_x = sess.run([grad_op, x])
        print('Iteration:', i,', x:', new_x)
```

and you get:

```
Iteration: 0 , x: 1.0
Iteration: 1 , x: 0.6
Iteration: 2 , x: 0.36
Iteration: 3 , x: 0.216
Iteration: 4 , x: 0.07776
Iteration: 5 , x: 0.07776
Iteration: 6 , x: 0.046656
Iteration: 7 , x: 0.01679616
Iteration: 8 , x: 0.010077696
Iteration: 9 , x: 0.010077696
```

which you see in converging to the true answer which is 0.

If you increase the learning rate of `GradientDescentOptimizer`, from 0.2 to 0.4, it will converge to 0 much faster.

**EDIT**

OK, based on my new understanding of the question, to manually implement gradient descent, you cannot do `x = x - alpha * gradient` because this is python operation which simply replaces the object `x`. You need to tell tensorflow to add the op to the graph, and this can be done using `x.assign`. It will look like:

```
x = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=True)
y = x**2 + 2

grad = tf.gradients(y, x)
# grad_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(y)

update_op = x.assign(x - 0.2*grad[0])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10):
        new_x = sess.run([update_op, x])
        print('Iteration:', i,', x:', new_x)
```

and we get the same answer as the native `GradientDescentOptimizer`:

```
Iteration: 0 , x: 1.0
Iteration: 1 , x: 0.6
Iteration: 2 , x: 0.36
Iteration: 3 , x: 0.1296
Iteration: 4 , x: 0.1296
Iteration: 5 , x: 0.077759996
Iteration: 6 , x: 0.046655998
Iteration: 7 , x: 0.027993599
Iteration: 8 , x: 0.01679616
Iteration: 9 , x: 0.010077696
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to do this part "grad_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(y)" manually, like so "x = x - gradient", is this possible?

Comment: OK, if I get it correctly this time, you can see my updated answer above under EDIT.

Comment: @Gerges Can we not add a stopping criteria? Eg. using L-infinity norm